# jQuery validating multiple radio buttons

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-group

Ok so the below script works really good at running through a form I have but I can figure out how to make it change the css properties.  The script is supposed to run though all the radio button groups on a form and identify which ones don't have any selection made.  Those without a selection I would like to highlight with the css shadow property.  Anyone know how to make this code work correctly?

```
    var radio_groups = {}
    $(":radio").each(function(){    
              radio_groups[this.name] = true;
            })
             for(group in radio_groups){
                if (!!$(":radio[name="+group+"]:checked").length) {

                }
                else{
                    hasError = true;
                    radio_groups[group].css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 3px #aaa');


             }}
```

Comment: With all that DOM traversal (.children, .find, etc) it is impossible to help without seeing the HTML. How do you know you are selecting/checking the correct elements?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out...

```
    for(group in radio_groups){
                if (!!$(":radio[name="+group+"]:checked").length) {
                    $(":radio[name="+group+"]").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 0px #FF0000');
                }
                else{
                    hasError = true;
                    $(":radio[name="+group+"]").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 4px #FF0000');


             }}
```